# Split lines and assign new id to them in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have some traffic crash points. I also have a road network. A traffic crash point is on one linestring. I want to use st_split to split the linestring into two parts and need to assign a new id to one of the substrings (OR: add two new substrings and then delete the old one). How can I incrementally assign id to them? (I mean I have many crash points and so have to assign IDs to them differently?)  I am just not familiar with indexing in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Basic information is missing: Table definition, Postgres version, sample values, the query you tried (even if it's not working). And obviously you are using PostGIS (version?), which should be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't want to make a new *record* from one `linestring`. Instead you want to make two (or more) *columns* from one column (`linestring`).

You could add two columns to your table. Perform some update on the rows:

```
UPDATE my_table SET new_col1=..., new_col2=...
```

where `...` is some expression and/or function which produces the two halfs.

Then drop the unneeded column is desired.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN old_col.
```